# overflow hidden - problem in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

i am using this plugin http://www.wbotelhos.com/capty/ and i find that it have problems in **IE 7**

the overflow: hidden is not working (file js)

anyone know how this can be fixed? and if we can solve this issue i obviously will share with developer

thanks!

Comment: the code? you have the source in the link. I have exactly the same problem. That is a problem in the plug in, not in my code. You can see if you use the IE7 or 6 please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
this solve the issue:
```

line added:

```
position: 'relative',
```

final code

```
$wrapper.css({
            overflow:   'hidden',
            position: 'relative',
            height:     $this.height(),
            width:      $this.width()
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

before IE version 8, some style properties, including overflow, only apply to an element if the element has what IE calls the hasLayout attribute, set explicitly or automatically when its position is set to relative or absolute (set, not inherited). The doctype must **also** be one that does not force IE 'quirks' mode.

Comment: There are other ways to give an element layout, such as with zoom: 1.